# Best way to re-format JS code snipet

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I wanted to reformat below code in order to keep as minimum as possible Any suggestion to re-format below code and use it as one single method.

```
function Cookie_Exist(cookieName) {
         var all_cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
         for (i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
             var temp_cookie = all_cookies[i].split('=');
             var cookie_name = temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
             if (cookie_name === cookieName) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }

function Get_Cookie(cookieName) {
    var all_cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (i = 0; i < all_cookies.length; i++) {
       var temp_cookie = all_cookies[i].split('=');
       var cookie_name = temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
     if (cookie_name === cookieName) {
     return temp_cookie[1];
    }
 }
return null;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean *refactor* and not *reformat*?

Comment: There's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that's right word "refactor" - thanks Robert.

Comment: Why would you need `Cookie_Exist` at all? Just try to get the cookie and check for `null`.

Comment: `Has_cookie` shoud use `Get_cookie`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reparsing the cookies everytime one could do that once and build up a Map:

```
 const cookies = new Map(document.cookie.split(";").map(pair => pair.split("=")));
```

Then its as simple as

```
 cookies.get("name");
```

or

```
  cookies.has("name")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had to keep the function Cookie_Exist rather than @Jonas's method, you would do well to use the array methods rather than a for loop. The abstraction can make code shorter and clearer:

```
function Cookie_Exist(cookieName) {
  const allCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  return allCookies.includes(cookieStr => {
    const thisCookieName = cookieStr.split('=')[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    return cookieName === thisCookieName;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Cookie_Exist() function at all, it does the same as the Get_Cookie() function. Use the Get_Cookie() everywhere instead of Cookie_Exist() and check your result. If it is false, then the cookie does not exist. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify what you mean by 'as minimum as possible.' If you're referring to being efficient, you definitely should go the route suggested by Jonas W.

If you're referring to reducing line count? His answer also is a good one, but I would recommend not focusing too much on line counts. Readability should be your number one goal. In other words, what you should be trying to keep to a minimum is the number of mental hoops a human reader of your code must jump through to understand what is going on.

Also, the regex you're doing to strip whitespace can be replaced with [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) which exists for this purpose.

```
function parseCookie(cookie) {
    let { name, value } = cookie.split('=');
    return [ name.trim(), value ];
}

function parseCookies() {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
    return new Map(cookies.map(parseCookie))
}


// Usage:

const cookieMap = parseCookies();

cookieMap.has('name');

cookieMap.get('name'):
```